# White page in IE7 & 8 - Webshims / Polyfill issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer, polyfills

I've just finished a small web project using Twitter Bootstrap and Wordpress, but unfortunately Internet Explorer has some problems with it. Opera, Safari and Chrome display the page without errors.

In IE10 & IE9 everything looks good, but IE8 & IE7 only display a white page. I already did a Google search to find a solution for that "White Screen of Death" (WSOD), but I was let down.

I also did some debugging on the page itself. That way I found out that a polyfill for HTML5 forms was causing the problem. I am using [Webshims](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/) for that. On the page it states IE6+ compatibility, but as you can see this is not the case, which is strange.

So I looked into the FireBug console to see if there are any JavaScript errors. There weren't any errors, but there was a warning, located in the script that causes trouble:

`Call webshims.polyfill before DOM-Ready or set waitReady to false.`

So I took a look into the documentation and set `waitReady` to `false` because I load the script at the bottom of the page. As a result, the warning was gone - but IE8 & IE7 still only display a white page! As a test I again removed the call to the script, the page works in IE8 & 7. As soon as I add the call again - white page.

After hours of being puzzled, one thing came to my mind: As a default, jQuery in Wordpress runs in no conflict mode, meaning instead of writing `$("#something)` you have to write `jQuery("#something")`. My idea was that this could cause some problems, so I deactivated the no conflict mode. Still: Nothing, white page.

I don't have any more ideas what could cause the problem, so I am asking you: Did you ever encounter that problem? Do you have any solutions or ideas for solutions?

Any input is really appreciated!

Comment: I have another idea: Could this problem be caused by IE7 & IE8 inability to render HTML5 elements? Of course I also used the HTML5 doctype. As said above I am using webshims, but do I need to call something special to enable the polyfill for HTML5 elements in legacy browsers? At the moment, I am only calling ` $.webshims.polyfill( "forms" );`, but on the webshims homepage it says `IE8- isn't capable of rendering HTML5 elements. Webshims lib in combination with Modernizr automatically fixes this issue...`. Or do I need to add another HTML5shiv script?

Comment: From your description it is hard to guess, what's going wrong there. As author of webshims. I'm pretty sure, I find the problem very fast, if you could give me access to your site, prototype, backuped site (wget). Could you somehow give me access?

Comment: Just loked at the site and can't reproduce your problem (tested with real IE7 and IE8, IETester and IE7/8 modes of IE9). Do you have a specific configuration or do I need to do some special?

Comment: Well that's strange. I only tested it using [http://netrenderer.de](http://netrenderer.de). If you select IE7 or 8 there, it renders a blank page. So maybe it's just a fault on there side.